# Problems setting up webstorm, angularjs and karma

Tags: angularjs, webstorm, karma-runner

I have some problems setting up Webstorm with Karma.
If I choose live edit, I can see my app in Chrome. 
If I start karma in Webstorm and refresh my app in chrome, the browser does not render angular ng-view directives.
If I stop karma and refresh the browser, the views are displayed again. Any ideas?

Another problem as well:
When I start up karma, it runs the unit tests in say 0.003 seconds etc, but from the second time onward it uses 3 seconds per test.

Comment: haven't seen anything of this kind... What WS build do you use - is it version 6.* or WS 7 EAP? How do you run karma - using node.js run configuration? My steps: 1. alt+f2 to preview my html in Chrome (Live Edit is on) - ok; 2. run karma server via node.js run configuration - server started, CVhrome captured, ok; page still renderd correctly 3. run tests (via another node.js configuration) - ok. My ng views are still correcly rendered. Tried similat steps in WS 7 (using karma run configuration and js debugger for live edit) - again everything is ok. Your steps + sample project would be helpful

Comment: and one more question: can you provide the contents of extension console (see http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/WI/LiveEdit, How do I know what's wrong?)?

Comment: Hi and thanks for answering. I started a new project and then it all seemed to work. I will come back to this if I stumble upon the same problems again. But I'm not so sure if karma had anything to do with it because I was able to make the directives not render without it as well. 
I will write again if I encounter the same issues.